# i am getting gradle build error after update android studio in 3.6.1,please help how to resolved

Tags: android

Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Comment: Do you have any ORM implementation in your project? I have same problem because of GreenDao dependency in my project, without it gradle builds just fine. So in my case all i had to do is just update gradle dependency

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when something goes wrong in Android Studio's first launch (eg. system crash, connection loss or whatever).

**Automatically**

To resolve this issue close Android Studio and delete the following directory's content, necessary files will be downloaded on IDE's next launch.

Windows: C:\Users\your-username.gradle\wrapper\dists

And then restart you android studio so android studio downloaded it automatically.

OR

You can also download it manually and add it i to your android studio

**Manually**

1) Manually download Gradle 6.2.2 binary (direct link: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2.2-bin.zip)

2) Open your android studio root directory, and extract the zip to the gradle folde

3) Open Android Studio, go to File->Settings->Build, Exectution, Deployment->Gradle and set "Gradle home" to point your new gradle-6.2.2 folder.

4) Sync and you are ready to go!

But i will recomend you to do not use manually ,letting Android Studio itself to do it.

Thanks

Comment: i have one more project working fine with same gradle but this one is not working.thanks

Comment: this solution is not working for me..thanks

Comment: That is all for my side thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing /youruserhome/.Gradle ?

Also, this may help alot: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-studio-is-borked-my-checklist-for-fixing-build-issues-e41a9dd8cba8

Answer (score 1):

try invalidate cache and restart.

Go to File >> Invalidate cache / Restart >> again Invalidate cache / Restart (in the pop-up)

Comment: i have already done many time but getting same error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I too had multiple problems related to Android Studio upgrade to 3.6.1. tried many workarounds and fixes but none of them worked for me, so I downgraded my Android Studio to last stable version viz [Android Studio 3.5.3](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.5.3.0/android-studio-ide-191.6010548-linux.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

first of check your current working project android Gradle plugin version and Gradle version 
Go to File >> Project stretcher (in the pop-up) to change project android Gradle plugin version and Gradle version  to same as current project